# Google speech adds extra digits and mis-transcribes 9 and 10 digit strings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Scenario: a user speaks a 9 or 10 digit ID and Google speech is used to transcribe it.

Google STT sometimes forces the number into a phone number format, adding mystery digits to make it fit (and thus failing to capture the number accurately).

For example if the caller says "485839485", it may come out as "485-839-4850",  with an extra digit that the caller never said. Digits are sometimes added in the middle of the number as well.

This happens even with added hints such as "one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero"

Has anyone found a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source speech recognition toolkits which will recognize number sequences reliably and for free, you just need to spend an hour to setup them.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be related to the logic used by the API's model when performing the transcription tasks. Since this issue is part of an internal process that tries to fit the transcribed numbers into a phone format, I don't think there is a current workaround for this scenario; however, I recommend you to take a look on [this ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/118204401) that has been created to review this issue, as well as the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/release-notes) documentation of Speech-to-Text API to keep the track of the new functionalities added to the service.